# When I debug a Ruta Script it takes too much time to load

Tags: debugging, uima, ruta

When I debug a Ruta Script it takes too much time to load the output file.  How long does it normally take?

Comment: Similarly in TextRuler view, Is there any limitation in the Number of Input for Training Data.Because It's taking too much time.Sometimes it's generating the rules orelse it's showing some GC overhead limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a current limitation of the CAS Editor in UIMA 2.8.1, to be more precise, it's the xmi deserialization. The situation will improve in UIMA 2.9.0/Ruta 2.5.0 when binary CAS formats will be supported in the CAS Editor.

For now, I recommend to reduce the amount of debug annotation in your CAS, e.g., by modularizing your script (debugging only a part of it) or splitting your document, removeing BRuta Basic and TokenSeed annoations with the configuration parameter `removeBasics`

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*